# Getting Here Map Road types from ROUTE TYPES and ISO COUNTRY CODE

Tags: heremaps

I have datasets of route types and iso country code but do not know how to get the road type from these.

Comment: You can use the "calculateroute" endpoint together with &attributes=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1(*) to get the road type. It returns a json value "ROUTE_TYPES" from 1...6 and each integer depending on the "ISO_COUNTRY_CODE" represents a road type. eg. ISO_COUNTRY_CODE:DEU with ROUTE_TYPES:2 is an Autobahn (motorway).

Comment: but i cannot get any info about this in the here documentation